# How can I get a value from a form in page 1 to another page by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have only learned HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery and I want to get a value from my `form` to my `index` page, which is located in different files, using the languages I know. So this is my form :

```
<form action="../index/index.html" method="GET">
  <label for="name">Name :</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
  <label for="email">Email :</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="eg.yourname@gmail.com" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

I want the value that a user submits in the `#name` `input` in my index's `div` tag when the `submit` button is pressed (this `div` has the class `sing-in`).

Both pages have their own JavaScript and CSS so if I would import the JavaScript of the page where the form is to my `index` pages it will mess up both pages I guess. Therefore, I want to do this without importing the JavaScript and just by taking the value from another page into my index page. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you submit your form and get redrected to your index page the values of the form will be put at the end of the url as GET parameters.

Example url: `localhost:80/index/index.html?name=Eddie&email=eddie@gmail.com`

To read the GET parameters you can use this code:

```
var urlString = window.location.href
var url = new URL(urlString);
var name = url.searchParams.get("name");
var email = url.searchParams.get("email");
//Check if name and email are set
```

Make sure to check if name and email have actually been set in index.html

Comment: but this will only work when server request is get request, what if form method set to post ?

Comment: Well, it isn't set to POST. 
But if it was that that would be another problem since you can only read POST parameters server-side.

Comment: yaa you are right, then it means we have to update the question, because questions context leads me to find values from html element in javaScript or in jquery

Comment: Question should be like, how can i get the user entered values in input box, after clicking submit buttons and form type is get

Comment: Thanks Wendelin your code works nicely, but what exatly i want to do to take that name and replace my Sing-in button of my index page. So after using your code, the problem i have is when  i open my index page it shows "null" written on my Sing-in button and i get that its because we have said take value from the name input which is empty. So my question is how can I have a button with "Sing-in" written on it and not "null"???

Comment: In that case you have two options: 1. Save the username in a database on your server 2. Save the username in JavaScript's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values from for like this:

if this is the form

```
<form action="../index/index.html" method="GET">
  <label for="name">Name :</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
  <label for="email">Email :</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="eg.yourname@gmail.com" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var email =  document.getElementById('email').value;
```

or in jquery

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
```

have a look:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

this might help you